# Matplotlib (Python) lento para plotar um gráfico 2-D?

Tags: python, desempenho, otimização, matplotlib

Ultimamente me surgiu a necessidade de se usar o Python para plotagem de gráficos com mais de 3600 coordenadas, porém percebi que o tempo pode ser um problema, porém não tenho certeza se o código que fiz tem algum problema de performance ou se é da library mesmo:

```
plt.figure()

for k in range(len(tempo)):
    plt.plot(tempo,tensao, color='black')

fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.5
plt.ylim([-1,2])
plt.xlim([min(tempo),max(tempo)])
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('resultadoPlot.jpeg', dpi=1200, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Quanto a esta parte:
for k in range(len(tempo)):
    plt.plot(tempo,tensao, color='black')

O que voce ta fazendo com isso? qual e a finalidade desta parte do codigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se considerarmos que o objeto `tempo` é um iterável de 3600 valores, no código

```
for k in range(len(tempo)):
    plt.plot(tempo,tensao, color='black')
```

você estaria gerando o mesmo gráfico 3600 vezes, o que provavelmente é a razão da lentidão. Se tanto `tempo` quanto `tensao` são iteráveis (lista), basta você fazer a chamada direta à função `plot` passando os dois objetos como parâmetro:

```
plt.plot(tempo, tensao, color='black')
```

---

**Adendo**

Mesmo sendo desnecessário na solução real do problema, em Python, você jamais faz a seguinte estrutura:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    ...
```

Pois essa é estrutura é considerada vício de linguagem e possui vários aspectos negativos quando considerado performance, semântica e legibilidade. Quase sempre, nesses casos, a solução é apenas:

```
for i in X:
    ...
```

Mas, lembrando, para o caso da pergunta, este laço de repetição é desnecessário.

Comment: Muito obrigado, meu Python anda bem enferrujado, forte abraço.